# I want to append indexes of an array into a <td> where select options are indexes of the array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want a situation where I can append the indexes of an array as options in a select. The code below fails.

```html
<?php 
    $str4 = "select * from fee_names where status = '1' "; 
    $res4 = mysql_query($str4) or die(mysql_error()); 
    while ($r4 = mysql_fetch_assoc($res4)){ 
        $name = $r4['NAME']; 
        array_push($fee_nameArray,$name); 
    }
>?
<input type="text" name="fee_name" id="fee_name" value="<?php echo $fee_nameArray; ?>">
```

```js
$('#addClasses').click(function(){
    var arrayNAme = $('#fee_name').val();
    //alert(arrayNAme.length); return false;
    row++;
    $('#count').val(row);
    var feeName = "feeName"+row;
    var feeCat = "feeCat"+row;
    var freq = "freq"+row;
    var others = "others"+row;
    var mandate = "mandate"+row;
    var rowID = "rowID"+row;
    $('#table_mile35').prepend('<tr id="' + rowID + '"><td><select class="form-control" id="' + feeName + '" name="' + feeName + '" required><option value="" selected="selected">--Choose Class--</option>'
    for (i = 0; i < arrayNAme.length; i++) {
        '<option value="' + arrayNAme[i] + '">' + arrayNAme[i] + '</option>'
    }
    '</select></td><td><input type="text" class="form-control input-sm "  name="' + feeCat + '" id="' + feeCat + '" placeholder="school fees related, club related" required></td><td><input type="text" class="form-control input-sm "  name="' + freq + '" id="' + freq + '" placeholder="Yearly, Monthly" required></td><td><textarea type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="' + others + '" id="' + others + '" placeholder="other relevant information" ></textarea></td><td><input type="checkbox"  name="' + mandate + '" id="' + mandate + '" value="1"></td></tr>');
 });
```

Comment: Firstly you can't put a `for` loop in the middle of a string, you need to append the values. Secondly, `arrayNAme` is a string, so iterating over it will only give you each character of the string individually, which I don't believe is the behaviour you're looking for.

Comment: What is arrayNAme here??

Comment: Can you show the value of arrayNAme here?

Comment: arrayNAme  is not a string, its an array already existing as a value in the DOM. Is their a better way of dynamically appending the indexes of an array as options in a select tag? @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: your code is completly wrong. Say pls, what you are expecting from this, or what you want to do) And show us an array maybe, jsfiddle - better

Comment: @dumebi given your code example, `arrayNAme` is *definitely* a string: `var arrayNAme = $('#fee_name').val();`.

Comment: @AjuJohn the values of arrayNAme = Tuition Fee,Book Fee,Registration Fee....

Comment: <?php $str4="select * from fee_names where status = '1' ";
$res4=mysql_query($str4) or die(mysql_error());                                                    while($r4 = mysql_fetch_assoc($res4)){
 $name =  $r4['NAME'];
 array_push($fee_nameArray,$name);
}>?    //-------------on the dom----------------------//<input type="text" name="fee_name" id="fee_name" value="<?php echo $fee_nameArray; ?>"> @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: @dumebi I'm not sure what you're trying to show me? If you want to add more details, please edit your question so that the code is at least readable.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - Not **definitely** it could be a multi select or a set of checkboxes or something else that would give an array as a value.

Comment: Good point. It look in this case as though the OP has a group of textboxes, so it would be a string here.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - how did you determine that?

Comment: See OP's comment here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36891635/i-want-to-append-indexes-of-an-array-into-a-td-where-select-options-are-indexe?noredirect=1#comment61348566_36891635

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if arrayNAme is an array, Use like this:

```
$('#addClasses').click(function(){
    var arrayNAme = $('#fee_name').val();
    arrayNAme = arrayNAme.split(',');
    row++;
    $('#count').val(row);
    var feeName = "feeName"+row;
    var feeCat = "feeCat"+row;
    var freq = "freq"+row;
    var others = "others"+row;
    var mandate = "mandate"+row;
    var rowID = "rowID"+row;
    var html = '<tr id="' + rowID + '"><td><select class="form-control" id="' + feeName + '" name="' + feeName + '" required><option value="" selected="selected">--Choose Class--</option>';
    for (i = 0; i < arrayNAme.length; i++) {
        html += '<option value="' + arrayNAme[i] + '">' + arrayNAme[i] + '</option>';
    }
    html += '</select></td><td><input type="text" class="form-control input-sm "  name="' + feeCat + '" id="' + feeCat + '" placeholder="school fees related, club related" required></td><td><input type="text" class="form-control input-sm "  name="' + freq + '" id="' + freq + '" placeholder="Yearly, Monthly" required></td><td><textarea type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="' + others + '" id="' + others + '" placeholder="other relevant information" ></textarea></td><td><input type="checkbox"  name="' + mandate + '" id="' + mandate + '" value="1"></td></tr>';
    $('#table_mile35').prepend(html);
 });
```

I am supposing value of arrayNAme is comma seperated (for example: Tuition Fee,Book Fee,Registration Fee)